# Parse a string to parse command line arguments from a string?

Tags: php, string

Is there a native "PHP way" to parse command arguments from a string? For example, given the following string:

```
some random string --color=red --is_corvette=true
```

I want to create the following array:

`array(3) {
  ['color'] =>
  string(3) "red"
  ['is_corvette'] =>
  string(4) "true"
}`

So a flag is defined as "--" and the string after the flag determines the attribute and its corresponding value.

I know about PHP's getopt() function, but it seems that can only be used to parse arguments passed into a PHP script via the command line, and doesn't seem to be able to parse any string on demand

Comment: it can be done by tokenizing the string fairly easy

Comment: You can use PEAR's `Console_Getopt` class. It like `getopt` but accept string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to find each occurrence, then reformat its result to get precisely what you're expecting, like this:

```
$s = 'some random string --color=red --is_corvette=true';
preg_match_all(
  '/--((?:color|is_corvette)=[\S]+)/',
  $s, $matches
);
if ($matches AND $matches[1]) {
  foreach ($matches[1] AS $match) {
    $match = explode('=', $match);
    $result[$match[0]] = $match[1];
  }
}
```

Beyond the current example you may build a function for a more general use, taking in account a predefined set of possible keys and their default values:

```
function args_from_string($string, $set) {
    preg_match_all(
      '/--((?:' . implode('|', array_keys($set)) . ')=[\S]+)/',
      $string, $matches
    );
    if ($matches AND $matches[1]) {
      foreach ($matches[1] AS $match) {
        $match = explode('=', $match);
        $set[$match[0]] = $match[1];
      }
    }
    return $set;
}

$predefined_set = [
    'color'       => 'black',
    'is_corvette' => 'false',
    'other_arg'   => 'value',
    // ...
];
$current_set = args_from_string(
    'some random string --color=red --is_corvette=true',
    $predefined_set
);
```