# How to check if the string is in -key value format in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I want to validate a string which must be in the format of `-key1 value1 -key2 value2`.

The `key` allow upper/lowercase character, number and underscore. like `-key_1` or `-Key_name_2`

The `value` can be any string, but not a empty string. SO, `value` could be `value1`, `-value1`. Also, `value` could be `"value1WithQuote"` with double quote and we extract the value as `value1WithQuote` from the double quote.

The number of key value pair could be up to 10 pairs.

I try with the regex below, but it only check the first key

```bash
str="-mykey1 keyvalue1 -MY_KEY_2 keyvalue2"

regex="-([a-zA-Z]+)"
[[ $str =~ $regex ]] && echo "matched"
```

Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Can the value include ANY character? Specifically can in include "-" or " "?

Comment: Check how it's done in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512378/parse-a-string-to-parse-command-line-arguments-from-a-string

Comment: `regex='^-[a-zA-Z]+([[:blank:]]-[a-zA-Z]+)*$'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Will fail with `-MY_KEY_2 keyvalye2`

Comment: you can use a while loop along with the `=~` operator, check my answer plz.

Comment: @Uberhumus, the value could include "-", but not a empty string.

Comment: @ikhvjs, that's not an empty string, that a white space. :)

Comment: How does that string get populated? Chances are it should really be an array instead of a string.

Comment: @EdMorton, it is actually a validation step.

Comment: @Uberhumus, Thanks for correction, double quote " " is acceptable.

Comment: @ikhvjs, so do you have any way of knowing when a value has ended? It sounds like theoretically you could get `"-mykey1 keyvalue1 -MY_KEY_2 keyvalue2 -MY_KEY_2"` because the value for `-mykey1` could be `keyvalue1 -MY_KEY_2 keyvalue2`. Is there any way to differentiate the key from the value?

Comment: Regarding [it is actually a validation step.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77080194/how-to-check-if-the-string-is-in-key-value-format-in-bash?noredirect=1#comment135887984_77080194) that doesn't explain why you're working with a string instead of an array. Just in general, you should not create a string from a series of `key value` pairs as that immediately makes it much harder to work with than an array and it's usually just as easy, if not easier, to create an array instead of a string right away.

Comment: @Uberhumus, I miss one of the scenario. I will update the question.

Comment: @EdMorton, the input from the client is a string. But yes, we can validate it using anyway we want.

Comment: How does your code receive that string? Read from stdin or passed as arguments or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton arguments

Comment: OK, then it's not a string, it's a list of arguments and as such can be treated as an array. The problem is that as soon as it's a string where "The value can be any string" you're screwed - you cannot robustly validate input like that because a `value` could be `this -foo that` and then it's indistinguishable from a value `this` followed by a second key `-foo` and a second value `that`.

Comment: @EdMorton, could you show a example? If value is `this -foo that`, it should double quoted with `"this -foo that"` instead. I also update my question for this. Sorry for this missing part.

Comment: If a value can be any string then it can include `"`s and so adding `"`s has no benefit and it's just a cludge when you should just be using arrays in the first place.

Comment: I just updated my answer to show storing your script arguments in an array rather than a string. Note that each argument is available in the array exactly as it was passed to your script, regardless of whether it contained blanks or quotes or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very good chance your starting `str` should actually have been populated as an array instead of a string, but here's how you could convert it to an array and use it as such now if none of your values can contain white space:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str="-mykey1 keyvalue1 -MY_KEY_2 keyvalue2 -this:that"

read -r -a arr <<<"$str"

regex='^-[[:alnum:]_]+$'
for (( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i+=2 )); do
    key="${arr[i]}"
    val="${arr[((i+1))]}"
    if [[ $key =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo "Key \"$key\" matched"
    else
        echo "Key \"$key\" did not match"
    fi
    if [[ -n $val ]]; then
        echo "Val \"$val\" is non-empty"
    else
        echo "Val \"$val\" is empty"
    fi
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Key "-mykey1" matched
Val "keyvalue1" is non-empty
Key "-MY_KEY_2" matched
Val "keyvalue2" is non-empty
Key "-this:that" did not match
Val "" is empty
```

As mentioned, the above assumes none of your values contain white space otherwise populating the array that way would fail.

---

EDIT: to show why you should be storing your arguments in an array rather than a string:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

args=()
for i in "$@"; do
    args+=( "$i" )
done

for (( i=0; i<${#args[@]}; i++ )); do
    printf 'Argument #%d = "%s"\n' "$i" "${args[i]}"
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh -key1 'this -foo that' -key2 value2
Argument #0 = "-key1"
Argument #1 = "this -foo that"
Argument #2 = "-key2"
Argument #3 = "value2"
```

The first loop is storing the arguments values in an array, the second is accessing their values.

I'm assuming you have some reason for wanting the arguments values to be stored at all, otherwise you could just do `for arg in "$@"` in that second loop above and get rid of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

I will iterate through the string and check for each key-value pair,it uses a modified regular expression `-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+) ([^ ]+)` where `([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)` matches the key and `([^ ]+)` matches the value and the `while` loop continues until no more key-value pairs are found in the string.

check this out

```
str="-mykey1 keyvalue1 -MY_KEY_2 keyvalue2"

regex="-([a-zA-Z_0-9]+) ([^ ]+)"
while [[ $str =~ $regex ]]; do
    key="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    value="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    echo "Key: $key, Value: $value"
    str="${str/${BASH_REMATCH[0]}/}"
done
```

**update**

As you requested I will extract the key-value pairs from the string and store them in an associative array (`keyValuePairs`),I also performs additional checks for duplicate keys, empty values, and the maximum number of key-value pairs and finally, it prints the extracted key-value pairs!

```
str="-mykey1 keyvalue1 -MY_KEY_2 keyvalue2"

#regex pattern for key-value pairs
regex="-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s+([^-\s]+)"

#array to store the extracted key-value pairs
declare -A keyValuePairs

#iterate through the string and extract key-value pairs
while [[ $str =~ $regex ]]; do
  key="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  value="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  
  #checking if the key already exists
  if [[ ${keyValuePairs[$key]+_} ]]; then
    echo "Duplicate key: $key"
    exit 1
  fi

  #checking if the value is empty
  if [[ -z $value ]]; then
    echo "Empty value for key: $key"
    exit 1
  fi
  
  #storing the key-value pair in the array
  keyValuePairs[$key]=$value
  
  #removing the matched key-value pair from the string
  str=${str/${BASH_REMATCH[0]}/}
done

#checking the number of key-value pairs
numPairs=${#keyValuePairs[@]}
if (( numPairs > 10 )); then
  echo "Too many key-value pairs. Maximum is 10."
  exit 1
fi

#printing the extracted key-value pairs
for key in "${!keyValuePairs[@]}"; do
  value="${keyValuePairs[$key]}"
  echo "Key: $key, Value: $value"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I update my queston to mention value could not be a empty string. Could you also handle this situation? So value can be also "-value1"

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```bash
str="-mykey1 keyvalue1 -MY_KEY_2 keyvalue2"
regex='^-[a-zA-Z0-9_]+( [a-zA-Z0-9]+)?( -[a-zA-Z0-9_]+( [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?){0,9}$'
[[ $str =~ $regex ]] && echo "matched"
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` - one or more letters/digits/underscores
- `( [a-zA-Z0-9]+)?` - an optional occurrence of:

  - - a space
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more letters/digits
- `( -[a-zA-Z0-9_]+( [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?)*` - zero or more occurrences of a space + the same pattern as above
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. The number of key value pair could be up to 10 pairs. So, value could not be a empty string and it can be "-value1"

Comment: @ikhvjs Just make the `<space>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` part optional, i.e. `( [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?` and replace the last `*` to `{0,9}` to set the limit on the number of additional options.